# .bat script to remove trailing whitespace

Tags: c++, c, windows, batch-file, scripting

I am fairly new to making scripts through windows. Maybe I even need something other than a script. I've done some similar things in linux using sed with a csv file but I'm wanting to make a .bat script file (or something similar) that would take in a c header file and remove all trailing white space.

edit Reason: (My Svn repo doesn't allow trailing White spaces and when working with a C++ UI Form it adds comments with trailing white space every time I add a new object, like a button for example)

edit:
it happens after comments like these shown below

```
        "// 
         // outputStringsTab
         // "
```

example snippit:

```
#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
      /// <summary>
      /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
      /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
      /// </summary>
      void InitializeComponent(void)
      {
         this->tabCollection = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabControl());
         this->outputStringsTab = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage());
         this->justificationComboBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
         this->stringSizeDropBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());
         this->stringFontLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->stringSizeLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->stringBackgroundLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->fontCheckListBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckedListBox());
         this->greenRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->blueRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->whiteRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->blackRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->shapePage = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage());
         this->circleAngleGroupBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
         this->circleAngleLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->circleAngleStartTextBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
         this->circleAngleEndTextBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
         this->circleAngleButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
         this->startAngleLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->degreesLabel2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->endAngleLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->degreesLabel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->lineSuppresionGroupBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
         this->squareLineLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->noneSuppressRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->topSuppressRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->bottomSuppressRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->leftSuppressRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->rightSuppressRadio = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->sizeGroupBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
         this->circleRadioButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->shapesHeightWidthLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->squareRadioButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->heightTextBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
         this->heightLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->sizeSendButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
         this->widthLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->widthTextBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
         this->gaugeTabPage = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TabPage());
         this->gaugeValueGroupBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
         this->barValueRadioButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->meterValueRadioButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->arcValueRadioButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RadioButton());
         this->gaugeValueTrackBar = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TrackBar());
         this->trackBarLabel = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
         this->tabCollection->SuspendLayout();
         this->outputStringsTab->SuspendLayout();
         this->shapePage->SuspendLayout();
         this->circleAngleGroupBox->SuspendLayout();
         this->lineSuppresionGroupBox->SuspendLayout();
         this->sizeGroupBox->SuspendLayout();
         this->gaugeTabPage->SuspendLayout();
         this->gaugeValueGroupBox->SuspendLayout();
         (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->gaugeValueTrackBar))->BeginInit();
         this->SuspendLayout();
         // 
         // tabCollection
         // 
         this->tabCollection->Controls->Add(this->outputStringsTab);
         this->tabCollection->Controls->Add(this->shapePage);
         this->tabCollection->Controls->Add(this->gaugeTabPage);
         this->tabCollection->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
         this->tabCollection->Name = L"tabCollection";
         this->tabCollection->SelectedIndex = 0;
         this->tabCollection->Size = System::Drawing::Size(827, 396);
         this->tabCollection->TabIndex = 0;
         // 
         // outputStringsTab
         // 
         this->outputStringsTab->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->justificationComboBox);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->stringSizeDropBox);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->stringFontLabel);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->label7);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->stringSizeLabel);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->stringBackgroundLabel);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->fontCheckListBox);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->greenRadio);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->blueRadio);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->whiteRadio);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->blackRadio);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->label4);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->label3);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->label2);
         this->outputStringsTab->Controls->Add(this->label1);
         this->outputStringsTab->Location = System::Drawing::Point(4, 22);
         this->outputStringsTab->Name = L"outputStringsTab";
         this->outputStringsTab->Padding = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(3);
         this->outputStringsTab->Size = System::Drawing::Size(819, 370);
         this->outputStringsTab->TabIndex = 0;
         this->outputStringsTab->Text = L"Output Strings";
         // 
         // justificationComboBox
         // 
         this->justificationComboBox->FormattingEnabled = true;
         this->justificationComboBox->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(3) { L"Left", L"Middle", L"Right" });
```

... etc.

Comment: Why is this a C or C++ issue?  I suggest removing the C and C++ tags since you are talking about a batch file using the MSDOS scripting language.

Comment: My Svn repo doesn't allow trailing White spaces and when working with a C++ UI Form it adds comments with trailing white space every time I add a new object, like a button for example

Comment: If this were about C or C++, you would be presenting us a C or C++ program that trims trailing white space.

Comment: Just added ;) new to asking on here

Comment: and I was in fact talking about C as this is about a C windows form generating this. As I said in the question "a c header file"

Answer (score 0):

Windows batch scripts do not provide a Turing complete programming language, and are primarily used for exactly what the name implies - batching together multiple commands (that you would otherwise execute from the command line).  Modern Windows does offer a great number of extensions over MS-DOS batch files, but it is still not a suitable tool for doing what you are asking.

Windows now includes [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) as an alternative to basic command line processor and batch files; you may be better off using that, but goven that your are presumably working with C and C++ is would be simple enough to write your own utility in the languages you are already familiar with perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

**TrimSpace**

```
filter ts {l|r|lr|lc count}
```

Trims leading and trailing spaces on a line.

> l - removes leading spaces.
>
> r - removes trailing spaces.
>
> lr - removes leading and trailing spaces.
>
> lc - removes `<count>` leading spaces.

**Example**

Fixes win.ini, not that it needs fixing, and sends it to the screen

```
filter trimspace lc 5 <"%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

The vbs script

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

If LCase(Arg(1)) = "l" then 
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        outp.writeline LTrim(Line)
    Loop
ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "r" then
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        outp.writeline RTrim(Line)
    Loop
ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "lr" then
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        outp.writeline Trim(Line)
    Loop
ElseIf LCase(Arg(1)) = "lc" then
    Count = Cint(LCase(Arg(2)))
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        If Left(Line,Count) = Space(Count) then
            outp.writeline Mid(Line, Count +1)
        Else
            outp.writeline LTrim(Line)
        End If
    Loop
End If
```

Use a batch file to start it like so

```
  cscript //nologo <pathtovbsscript\vbsscript.vbs> lc 5 <file.h
```

**General Use**

Filter is for use in a command prompt. Filter.vbs must be run with cscript.exe. If you just type filter it will run a batch file that will do this automatically.

```
 filter subcommand [parameters]
```

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command
```